# Rule/Macro to rename pdf files and resend to different recipient?

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I rename a **`pdf`** attachment the same as the subject line and then email the renamed file to a different recipient.

For instance, the email I receive will have a subject line of **`"123456-CHM78912"`** but the attachment **`pdf`** name will be **`"INV-5"`**.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have tried/started so far? have [searched?](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I don't really know where to start. My programming knowledge is limited at best.Also, everything I have searched only renames the file, it doesn't email it to a new recipient. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Set your outlook rule and call the following scrip,

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveAtmts(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Path As String
    Dim SaveAtmt As String
    Dim AtmtName As String

    Path = "C:\Temp\"
    AtmtName = Item.Subject & ".pdf"

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
            SaveAtmt = Path & AtmtName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveAtmt
        End If
    Next

'   // Email the file
    Set Item = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With Item
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .body = AtmtName & " Report Attached "
        .To = "0m3r@Email.com"
        .Attachments.Add SaveAtmt
'        // Display msg
'        .Display
'        ' Or Send
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, I set this up in Visual Basic editor in Outlook and created a rule to tell Outlook to run this script. It only works when I am exiting the Rules and Alerts editor and check the box that says "Run this rule now" If I do that, it works perfectly, but it will not work automatically when an email arrives in the inbox.

Comment: @CharlesHolden if it runs then there is nothing wrong with code, restart your  Outlook and see if the  [macro is allowed to run](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7B4FDD2E-174F-47E2-9611-9EFE4F860B12?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) also look in to [Digitally sign your macro project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956E9CC8-BBF6-4365-8BFA-98505ECD1C01)